# How to add check for all test cases in Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, webautomation

I'm running test cases to check on several pages, but I want to include the same basic checks on each page, e.g. all css, js files are returned, there is no "page not found" text on the page etc.

Is there a way to add standard checks?

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance..

All your pages should inherit from a 'BasicPage' which contains common tests .

However these tests SHOUD NOT have any dependencies with each other or the tests with the sub class tests as the order of these tests are not guaranteed.

Comment: Do you mean by tests can have inheritance? I had a look around the UI and couldn't see any mention of that.

Comment: Yes of course tests can have inheritance. If you run a derived class test, then base class tests will also run.
But their order cannot be guarateed

public class AAGPageTest extends BasicTest {
}